# How can I use the TinyMCE editor for the description field on a Media item?

Tags: media-library, tinymce

When I view an image in my Media Library, the Description field textarea has a toolbar, but it's only for creating HTML tags.

How can I get the TinyMCE wysywig editor to be used instead?

I've found plugins for enabling this editor for [users' biographies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-biography-editor/) and the [descriptions of taxonomy terms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-term-description-editor/) but not for media items.